# Optimize slow numpy n-body simulation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, simulation, physics

I am implementing a function to calculate the change in position of an object for an n-body simulation in python.

However, my implementation using numpy array operations is drastically slower than another implementation that just uses loops. How could I improve the speed of the numpy implementation?

- x[0] is an (n, 3) array containing n positions in 3 space
- M is an (n, ) array containing n masses

**Numpy implementation:**

```
    def dxdt(x):
        G = 1
        dx = np.empty_like(x)
        dx[0] = x[1]
        dx[1] = 0
        # mass matrix
        m_matrix = (M[None, :] * M[:, None])

        # Displacement matrix
        r_matrix = x[0][None, :] - x[0][:, None]

        # Distance
        d = linalg.norm(r_matrix, axis=2)
        d[d == 0] = 1

        forces = G*r_matrix* m_matrix[:, :, None]/np.expand_dims(d, 2)**3
        dx[1] += forces.sum(axis=1)/ M[:, None]
        return dx
```

- R is an (n, 3) array containing positions
  **Loop implementation:**

```
    def dxdt(x):
        dx = np.empty_like(x)
        dx[0] = x[1]
        dx[1] = 0
        for i in range(len(R)):
            for j in range(i):
                rij = x[0][j]-x[0][i]
                fij = M[i]*M[j]*rij/np.sum(rij**2)**1.5
                dx[1][i] += fij/M[i]
                dx[1][j] -= fij/M[j]
        return dx
```

When using timeit the numpy implementation takes 0.15027240006020293 ms
and the loops implementation takes 0.016941800004133256 ms

*** Here is sample data to run functions

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as linalg 
M  = [1,1e-2]         # Masses.
dt = 1e-2             # Time step.
r1 = 3                # Initial distance between the two objects.
v1 = np.sqrt(M[0]/r1) # Velocity needed for circular orbit.
t1 = 2*np.pi*r1/v1    # Period of the circular orbit.
R = np.array([[0.,0,0],[r1,0,0]])
V = np.array([[0.,0,0],[0,v1,0]])


# Make sure the initial conditions are numpy arrays.
R = np.array(R)
V = np.array(V)
M = np.array(M)
G = 9.81

X = [ np.array([R,V]) ]

def dxdt(x):
    G = 1
    m_matrix = (M[None, :] * M[:, None])

    # Displacement matrix
    r_matrix = x[0][None, :] - x[0][:, None]

    # Distance
    d = linalg.norm(r_matrix, axis=2)
    d[d == 0] = 1

    forces = G*r_matrix* m_matrix[:, :, None]/np.expand_dims(d, 2)**3
    return forces.sum(axis=1)/ M[:, None]

def dxdt(x):
        dx = np.empty_like(x)
        dx[0] = x[1]
        dx[1] = 0
        for i in range(len(R)):
            for j in range(i):
                rij = x[0][j]-x[0][i]
                fij = M[i]*M[j]*rij/np.sum(rij**2)**1.5
                dx[1][i] += fij/M[i]
                dx[1][j] -= fij/M[j]
        return dx
```

Comment: Not really a minimal working example. Could you at least provide some dummy data for x and M and include your import statements so I can actually run the damn thing? I made some arrays of cartesian coordinates and masses myself, but it throws an error for the norm function. You can't use axis=2 for an array of dimension = 2.

Comment: In your second implementation, I believe your `return` statement should not be inside the outer `for` loop. This is stopping the calculation very early and may explain the short run time (though it's hard to tell without some example data and confirmation that these two functions really calculate the same result).

Comment: No problem, sorry about not including sample data, ill update now.

Comment: I corrected the incorrectly indented return statement on the loops implementation which did help explain some of the discrepancy in time. However the numpy implementation is still much slower. Numpy implementation: 0.3313559999696736 ms. Loop implementation: 0.1479468000070483 ms. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @J.Doe `r_matrix` has a shape of (2, 2, 3) before the distance is computed.